# Problems with Compiz on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: unity, compiz, 14.04, lts

I am currently dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my system(3 gb RAM, i3 , 320 GB HDD).
I recently installed the Compiz Config Manager along with Compiz Pluginz. 
Realizing that they would not be much useful(And the fact that my system was behaving weird 10 mins into the installation) I uninstalled compiz pluginz. As a result however, i am unable to boot in ubuntu. I get past the login screen after which only my wallpaper is visible (i.e No Dash, Panel etc.) Which renders Ubuntu quite useless. What should I do to rectify this situation?

Comment: I think you have to reset compiz.